# How to prove that $\int-x^2e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{xe^{-ax^2}}{2a}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{a}x)}{4a^{3/2}}$

Tags: calculus

How can one prove that? $$\int-x^2e^{-ax^2}\,dx=\frac{xe^{-ax^2}}{2a}-\frac{ \sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erf} (\sqrt{a}\,x)}{4a^{3/2}}.$$
I really don't know how to proceed...

Comment: $u=x,dv=-xe^{-ax^2}$

Comment: @chubakueno Don't bother. Just take the derivative of the RHS :) Recall that $\frac{d}{dx} \operatorname{erf}(x) = \frac{2e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.

Comment: Alternatively, write $I(a) = \displaystyle\int e^{-(\sqrt{a} x)^2}dx = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{a\pi}}\text{erf} (\sqrt{a}x)$ and compute $\dfrac{dI}{da}$ via differentiation under the integral.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $~\displaystyle\int e^{-ax^2}dx=\sqrt{\dfrac\pi a}\cdot\frac{\text{erf}\Big(x\sqrt a\Big)}2$ . Now differentiate both sides with regard to *a*. :-)